# Custom Postgresql Sequence Nextval in SequelizeJS

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

How can i define sequence `nextval()` in sequelizeJS Model.

Is there any predefined function available for `nextval()` in sequelizeJS ?,

Is there any possiblity to write sequence `nextval()` custom function inside sequelize define model ?

Answer (score 3):

In case there is someone at this point who wants to do this as well, the best way to do it I guess is using `Sequelize.literal`:

```js
// on your model

const model = sequelize.define("model", {
  ...attributes,
  customSequence: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: sequelize.Sequelize.literal("nextval('custom_sequence')")
  },
})

// after create a migration for your new column

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query("CREATE SEQUENCE custom_sequence start 1020 increment 20",)

    await queryInterface.addColumn('table', 'customSequence', {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.Sequelize.literal("nextval('custom_sequence')")
    })
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP SEQUENCE custom_sequence')
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('table', 'customSequence')
  }
};
```

Comment: Will this take care of potential race conditions the way PostGres `nextVal()` does?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea, but I guess it will, considering that this will be executed at writing time.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way in sequelize to do so, kindly refer

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3555

Answer (score 2):

No predefined function for that. But you can make use of raw query and get nextval like

```
sequelize.query("SELECT nextval('sequence')", { 
 type: collection.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something similar as posted by @sebin and chaining the promise to my model.create(), like so:

```
  this.sequelize
    .query("SELECT max(cust_no) + 1 as 'custNo' from employees.customers", {
      type: this.sequelize.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
    .then(results => {
      return results[0];
    })
    .then(nextPk => {
      const values = Object.assign({}, newCustomer, nextPk);
      return customersModel.create(values);
    })
    .then(newRecord => {
      console.log('newRecord:', newRecord);
    });
```

In the above case I use max +1 but the solution applies to your sequence all the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly with MSSQL / MariaDB

**Sequelize.literal** in the "defaultValue" was the key.
I'm new to Sequelize, and luckily it lets me redefine the "id" field, which normally doesn't have to be specified in the model.
Happy day for me.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
const People = sequelize.define("people", {
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: sequelize.Sequelize.literal("NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.BAS_IDGEN_SEQ")
},...
```